# Need help diagnosing dell c6100 - No POST

Tags: hardware, dell-poweredge, electrical-power, diagnostic

Hi Server Fault Community,

I have 2 nodes in my [dell c6100](http://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/productdetails/poweredge-c6100) that are not POSTing, it's the top two nodes (1 & 3). The bottom 2 DO turn on (2 & 4). I need some help identifying which part I might need to replace.

My initial thought is that I need to replace the top power distribution board. 
[Dell c6100 Power Distribution Board YJ9Y6](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Dell-PowerEdge-C6100-1st-2nd-Power-Distribution-Board-YJ9Y6-TJ77Y-/222419577603?hash=item33c93d6b03:g:GnoAAOSwx6pYrIvZ)

Here are my BMC Sensor Logs. You can see that a handful of the sensors are unavailable.

**Dead node**[image]

**Working node**[image]

The working nodes have their green power light LEDs in the rear illuminated. The dead nodes do not have any color light on the LED - they don't illuminate.

The working nodes have their green power light indication illuminated on the front panel (the power switch), but the dead nodes do nothing when you press their power switches - no illumination, no POST or video output.

All node's ethernet ports illuminate and work, which is why I am able to remote into the BMC and grab the sensor logs.

When I try to power on a dead node via BMC, I get this error message,

> "Please check The feature connector cables".

I don't know what that means, do any of you?

[image]

Thanks for your help and suggestions!

**EDIT - 6/6/2017**

I have purchased replacement power distribution boards (top and bottom) from e-bay and swapped out the newer parts. I screwed down the new boards, reconnected all the cables, and booted up the server. This did not fix the problem. I should have done some basic diagnostics before buying the replacement part.

After the part replacement not yielding a positive result, I took the working node and slid it out the back and swapped its placement for the dead node right above. The known working node still worked, so that told me the problem with the dead node lies on the system board itself and not in any of the server parts powering that position.

Comment: Do you have a current support contract with Dell for this equipment?

Comment: No, I bought this refurbished off of eBay.

Answer (score 0):

One of my Nodes in my C6100 died mysteriously like this.

I removed the Node, stripped it down, gave it a good clean, using an air duster, mini vacuum etc, and took out CPU/RAM and re-seated them.

Also put fresh heat compound on the CPU before putting heat syncs back on.

You can download the official service manual for the server here:
https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_cloud_products/poweredge-c6100_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf

Once I reassembled the node it powered back up just fine.

I find that about once every year it's wise to just strip and clean the machine, the fact that these things are permanently switched on, and have the vibration of the fans etc running all the time, that you do occasionally get ram chips loosing contact and such like.

The other thing I also find helpful, is to clean the edge contacts with a clean white pencil eraser.  I have tried all sorts of things over the years, and nothing has ever come close to doing as good a job as a clean white pencil eraser does (  Works wonders on the chip on ATM & Bank cards too :-)  )

Remove the sleds, and clean the edge connectors where they slot into the front assembly.